# Add second child jquery toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that when you click on a record opens a second level giving the user the feeling of 
doing drill down, now it works just for one "child" or second level, but what I want know is to add a third level so when I click on any of the green options that appears on my fiddle a new level shows there.

This is the jquery code

```
$('.drillDown tr td:last-child, .drillDown tr th:last-child').hide();
$('.drillDown tr td:first-child, .drillDown tr th:first-child').click(function(){
    $('.drillDown tr td:last-child, .drillDown tr th:last-child').show();
})

$('table.drillDown').each(function() {

    var $table = $(this);
    $table.find('.parent').click(function() {
        console.log( "*****Click on Parent" );
        $(this).nextUntil('.parent').toggle("fast"); 

    });

    var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();
    $table.find('button.hide').click(function() {
        $childRows.hide();

    });

    $table.find('button.show').click(function() {
        console.log("*****Click on Child");
        $childRows.filter('.child').show();
    });

    $table.find('tr.child').click(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('.child').show()
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ny6qcxtd/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a third level called grandson :D

I updated this code:

```
        $table.find('.parent').click(function() {
            console.log( "*****Click on Parent" );
            $(this).nextUntil('.parent', ".child").toggle("fast"); 

        });

        $table.find('.child').click(function() {
            console.log( "*****Click on child" );
            $(this).nextUntil('.child', ".grandson").toggle("fast"); 

        });
```

You can click on the first parent and the first child to see the grandson.

Look: https://jsfiddle.net/ny6qcxtd/1/

Comment: Thanks for your time =)

Comment: I'm grad it can help.

Comment: One more question, the child and grandson are expanded and if I click on the parent the child collapse but the grandson stay expanded, I want the child and grandson to collapse when I click on the parent :)

Comment: Let's always hide the grandsons when you click on parents:

https://jsfiddle.net/ny6qcxtd/2/

Comment: `$(this).nextUntil('.parent', ".grandson").hide("fast");`

Comment: Thanks again, so kind from you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach that could apply to any number of sublevels. I'm using `data` attributes to give each `tr` a *level*. Try it below:

```js
$('table.drillDown').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this),
        $rows  = $table.find('tbody tr');

    // Hide non-parents
    $rows.not('.parent').hide();
    // On click on a row, toggle the sublevel
    $rows.on('click', toggleSublevel);

    function toggleSublevel()
    {
        // Get the sublevel of the current row
        var sublevel = parseInt($(this).data('level'), 10) + 1;
        //Get the next row
        $next = $(this).next();
        // While there is a "next" element and its level is greater or equal 
        while($next.length && $next.data('level') >= sublevel)
        {
            // If it's equal, toggle it
            if($next.data('level') == sublevel) $next.toggle();
            // If it's greater, hide it
            else $next.hide();
            // Go to the next one
            $next = $next.next();
        }
    }
});
```

```css
tbody tr{ cursor: pointer; }
thead tr{
    text-align: center;
    background: #eceded;
}
td{ padding: .2em .5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="drillDown">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Some column title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="parent" data-level="0"> <td>Parent category #1</td> </tr> 
            <tr data-level="1"> <td>Subcategory 1.1</td> </tr>
                <tr data-level="2"> <td>Subcategory 1.1.1</td> </tr>
                <tr data-level="2"> <td>Subcategory 1.1.2</td> </tr>
            <tr data-level="1"> <td>Subcategory 1.2</td> </tr>
                <tr data-level="2"> <td>Subcategory 1.2.1</td> </tr>
                <tr data-level="2"> <td>Subcategory 1.2.2</td> </tr>
        <tr class="parent" data-level="0"> <td>Parent category #2</td> </tr> 
            <tr data-level="1"> <td>Subcategory 2.1</td> </tr>
                <tr data-level="2"> <td>Subcategory 2.1.1</td> </tr>
                <tr data-level="2"> <td>Subcategory 2.1.2</td> </tr>
            <tr data-level="1"> <td>Subcategory 2.2</td> </tr>
                <tr data-level="2"> <td>Subcategory 2.2.1</td> </tr>
                <tr data-level="2"> <td>Subcategory 2.2.2</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :D